# Expanding a group by in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I've just started using Oracle ApEx and before I get too deep into it, I wanted to make sure certain functionality is built in.
Is there an easy way for me to have a report that expands and collapses nodes?
For example, Lets suppose I have a table:

```
STATE   CITY  POPULATION
```

And I want to present the user with a report where one row is showing

```
CALIFORNIA      100000000
```

And then they click on a (+) and it expands to

```
CALIFORNIA
    LOS ANGELES    10387487
    SANFRANCISCO     9278437
```

Etc.
I've just been skimming through some tutorials, and I haven't seen anything like that (which is fairly basic, I would think)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this using an APEX tree region as in [my demo here](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=36342:27):
[image]

First I created a view that unioned the state and city data together in the way a tree requires:

```
create or replace view state_city_view as
select state_name as name, '' as parent_name 
from state
union all
select city_name || ' ' || population name, state_name as parent_name
from city;
```

Then I used that as the source of a Tree Region like this:

[image]

Comment: alas...I was hoping for something more graceful than that.  Thanks!